# Why empty values were pulled based on the query?

Tags: sql, hql

I wrote basic query trying to pull the value `121`,`223`,`272`,`021`from a column called interest_rate `ir` in a table called `bank`. The data type for `ir` is char. The table is very big so I just limit it to 10 rows.

```
SELECT DATE, CUST_ID, TRADE_ID, IR FROM BANK WHERE IR IN ('121','223','272','021') LIMIT 10
```

However, I've only got 10 rows with empty values in the `IR` column. What is the problem here?

Comment: I am guessing that you are misinterpreting the results.  You should only tag with the database you are actually using, MySQL?  or Postgres?

Comment: MySQL or Postgres?  Can't be both.  Please tag properly.